# How to seek to the beginning of a topic?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

In C# how do you do this?  The library doesn't seem to match some other implementations.

I thought something like

```
using (var c = new Consumer<Ignore, string>(conf)) {

    c.Subscribe(topic);
    c.Assignment
       .ForEach(partition => c.Seek(new TopicPartitionOffset(partition, Offset.Beginning)));
}
```

but there are initially no assignments.  If I hook the event for `OnPartitionsAssigned`, the consumer still doesn't have a partition assigned and while the event has a partition, the consumer can't seek it.

I'm figuring there is a standard way to do this, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be something like this. you should just know about partition number that here is `0`:

```
using (var c = new Consumer<Ignore, string>(conf)) 
{
    TopicPartitionOffset tps = new TopicPartitionOffset(new TopicPartition("TOPIC", 0), 
    Offset.Beginning);
    c.Assign(tps);
}
```

Comment: Well, this works, but seems a bit painful if you have multiple partitions

Answer (score 0):

This example turned out to be absolutely working for me in the same situation:

```
public IConsumer<string, string> Consumer { get; }
public KCKeysKafkaConsumer(ConsumerConfig conf, string topic)
{
    Consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(conf)
        .SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) =>
        {
            return partitions.Select(tp => new TopicPartitionOffset(tp, Offset.Beginning));
        }).Build();
    Consumer.Subscribe(topic);
}
```